# Свой контейнер с Proxy class(c++)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется контейнер и прокси класс для него.

```
    template<class Key, class Mapped_Type, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
    struct PersistentMapProxy
    {
        PersistentMap<Key, Mapped_Type, Compare> & parent;
        Key key;
        Mapped_Type *value;
        //konstruktor
        PersistentMapProxy(PersistentMap<Key, Mapped_Type, Compare> & parent, Key key)
            : parent(parent), key(key),value(new Mapped_Type((*parent.find(key)).second))
        {

        }

        const Mapped_Type& operator = (const Mapped_Type& value_)   const
        {
            *value = value_;
            parent.insert(std::make_pair(key, value_));
            return *value;
        }



        //vrati hodnotu ze souboru
        operator Mapped_Type&() const
        {
            //PersistentMap<Key, Mapped_Type, Compare>::iterator it = parent.find(key);
            return *value;
        }

        ~PersistentMapProxy()
        {
            delete value;
        }
    };


    template <typename Key, typename FileType, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class PersistentMap {
        // ...

        typedef PersistentMapProxy<Key, FileType,Compare> Proxy;

        const Proxy operator[] (Key key)
        {
            return Proxy(*this, key);
        }

        void insert(std::pair(T1,T2) a){ /*...*/ }

        // ...
    };
```

Щас уточню вопрос, мой контейнер похож на map,  но сохраняет в памяти только ключ, а value  записывает в файл, название коего является ключем.

При `mymap[999] = 100;` 999 идет в АВЛ дерево, а потом создается файл с именем 999, и в него сохраняется значение 100.

проблема в том что мне нужно, дабы можно было провести такое действие:

```
   void modify(int& a) {
    a += 5;
}

myMap[2] = 20;
int c = 30;
modify(c);
modify(myMap[2]);
int a = myMap[1];
int b = myMap[2];
assert(b == 25);
myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;
```

то есть если я правильно понимаю, то мне нужно чтобы при `modify(myMap[2]);`, значение в `myMap[2]` тоже изменилось, а следовательно и в файле.

**UPD** На форуме посоветовали, что делать проверку на изменение ключа при уничтожении объекта крайне не желательно. Но я не нашел другого способа, можете посоветовать еще вариант?

К сожалению при проверке в деструкторе
`myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;`
дает не корректный результат. Вместо 45 дает 25.
из за того что прокси класс левой части уничтожается раньше правой, и он перезаписывается.
Можете посоветовать решение данной проблемы? Будет совсем идеально, если будет пример.
**UPD**
Пришел к мысли, что можно еще сделать класс структуру, которая будет использоваться для того чтобы разные инстанции прокси класса одного ключа, указывали на одно и то же место в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Код вовсе не должен скомпилироваться честным компилятором, т. к. прокси может преобразовываться только к `const Mapped_Type` и `const Mapped_Type&` а функция `modify` имеет сигнатуру `void modify(int& a)`.
Т. е. `modify` принимает `int&`, а `PersistentMapProxy` может отдать только значение `int` или неизменяемую ссылку на `int`.
Единственная возможность отработать вызов `modify(myMap[2]);`, это создать на стеке временную переменную для результата `myMap[2]` и её адрес передать в `modify`.
Понятно что при этом все изменения при вызове произойдут в этой переменной и после окончания вызова эта временная переменная станет недоступна.

Comment: Да я попробовал создать свой пример и он не компилится. http://cpp.sh/7xjd4

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я совместил случайно 2 версии программы. Теперь проблем с типами не будет, но вот как изменить код дабы провести операции `myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;` и `modify(myMap[2]);`, я не знаю.

Comment: При создании Proxy ты создаёшь в куче экземпляр `Mapped_Type` который и изменяешь. Что не влияет на реальное значение в дереве. К тому же ты теряешь память, не удаляя value в деструкторе.

Comment: Mapped_Type  не находится в дереве, в дереве только ключи. Потом я проверяю есть ли в дереве заданный в скобках ключ, и если есть(значит и файл существует) я беру из файла значение этого ключа. И я удаляю валуе в деструкторе, просто опять не добавил(

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы работало как заявлено, нужно разделить 2 случая:

1. `myMap[2] = ...` Для этого нужно вернуть из `operator[]` контейнера неконстантный экземпляр `Proxy`,а в `Proxy` добавить оператор присваивания с типом `Mapped_Type`, в котором изменять значение в контейнере.
2. `modify(myMap[2]);` - в этом случае в неконстантном экземпляре `Proxy`, нужно отдельное поле под значение `Mapped_Type`, а в деструкторе изменить значение в контейнере.

Comment: я хотел так сделать, но тогда возникает проблема с `myMap[2] = myMap[2] + 20;` так как правое прокси уничтожается последним и перезаписывает правильное левое значение.

Comment: В №1 я имел в виду оператор присваивания в классе `PersistentMapProxy` с сигнатурой `PersistentMapProxy& operator=(const Mapped_Type& val)`
его тело примерно такое:
```PersistentMapProxy& operator=(const Mapped_Type& val) {
  set_value(val);
  return *this;
}```

Comment: а  `const Mapped_Type& operator = (const Mapped_Type& value_)   const` разве не делает тоже самое?